# How to concatenate two columns so that one comes below the other in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, append, multiple-columns

```
  Col-1    Col-2
0 Erin     Tanya
1 Cathy    Tom
2 Ross     Wes
```

This is my dataset

I need the result to look like this:

```
  New_column
0 Erin
1 Cathy
2 Ross
3 Tanya
4 Tom
5 Wes
```

I tried using .map, append, concat and .ravel but no luck. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df1 = df[['Col-1','Col-2']].melt(value_name='New_column')[['New_column']]

print (df1)
  New_column
0       Erin
1      Cathy
2       Ross
3      Tanya
4        Tom
5        Wes
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), you can use:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'New_column': df.to_numpy().ravel(order='F')})

# or
out = pd.DataFrame({'New_column': np.ravel(df, order='F')})
```

output:

```
  New_column
0       Erin
1      Cathy
2       Ross
3      Tanya
4        Tom
5        Wes
```